# How to test Rest API call with swagger if needs authentication

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I have springfox-swagger2 (version 2.6.1) and springfox-swagger-ui (version 2.6.1) in spring application.

How to I can configure authorization token for calls which needs authorized for continue (how to set X-AUTH-TOKEN for swagger).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Define the following API key as the security scheme. In your cause a header called `X-AUTH-TOKEN`. We refer to this scheme using the key `mykey`.

```java
private ApiKey apiKey() {
  return new ApiKey("mykey", "X-AUTH-TOKEN", "header");
}
```

2. Setup the security context. This just means you're setting up what the authorization scope is for a given path in your API. For e.g. for `/anyPath/customers` we may require a scope of `accessEverything`.

```java
private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder()
        .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
        .forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/anyPath.*"))
        .build();
}

List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
  AuthorizationScope authorizationScope
      = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
  AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
  authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
  return newArrayList(
      new SecurityReference("myKey", authorizationScopes));
}
```

Then in your docket associate the newly created security context and security schemes.

```java
new Docket(...)
    .securitySchemes(newArrayList(apiKey()))
    .securityContexts(newArrayList(securityContext()))
```

Now to enable swagger UI you need to supply the following bean configuration

```java
@Bean
SecurityConfiguration security() {
  return new SecurityConfiguration(
      "test-app-client-id",
      "test-app-client-secret",
      "test-app-realm",
      "test-app",
      "YOUR_API_AUTH_TOKEN",
      ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER, 
      "X-AUTH-TOKEN", 
      "," /*scope separator*/);
}
```

This tells the swagger-ui that you're going to use the api key and provide an api auth token at build time (perhaps using an encrypted configuration property.

NOTE: The swagger-ui is limited in its configurability. It serves the 80% of uses cases. Additional customization might mean you won't be able to use the bundled swagger-ui.